# KeyError: u'no item named <name>'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this function which places data into another dataframe.

```
def set_var(self,navn,periode,value):
    try:
        if navn.upper() not in self.data:
            self.data[navn.upper()]=NaN
        self.data[navn.upper()].ix[periode]=value
    except:
        print('> fejl ved genmning af:',navn,'i',periode)
        print( self.data[navn.upper()])
    return
```

which I then iterate like this, this fill with data:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(bd):
    if val not in ('Navn','Type','Aarstal','Referenceperiode','Registreringsnummer','nummer','navn','navn1','period', 'regnr'):
        for row in bd.itertuples():
            banker.set_var((str(row[6])+'_'+str(val)),row[60], row[idx+1])
```

I get the error: `KeyError: u'no item named <name of first item I try to insert>'`

Why is this?

Comment: Remove the blanket except; the `self.data[navn.upper()]` is your error here, but the *real* error is being masked.

Answer (score 2):

A Key Error is typically because the dict object does not have the key you are requesting. It seems to me that self.data is a dict. If so, you could test your object by using has_key()... like so,

```
if self.data.has_key(navn.upper()):
        self.data[navn.upper()]=NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Self.data is a dataframe. The code you wrote unfortunately does not change anything.

Comment: If I run it manually it works, but somehow it the check goes wrong using the function. This runs wituout any problems: `if 'XXX' not in mindatabank.data: mindatabank.data['XXX']=NaN mindatabank.data ['XXX'].ix['2010Q2']=100 mindatabank.get_var('XXX',0,'2010Q2')`